# rm -rf と rmdir の違いって？

Tags: linux

`rm -rf example/`

と

`rmdir example/`

の違いがわかりません。
どのような違いがあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rmdir は空のフォルダしか削除できないです。

rm -rf はフォルダの中でファイルが存在すれば削除ができます。

例えば

```
mkdir example/
touch example/file1

rm -rf example/ はexampleのディレクトリーを隠しファイル以外削除できます。

rmdir example/　はexampleのディレクトリーを削除できないです。
rmdir: failed to remove `example': Directory not empty
```

Comment: `rm -r`についてですが、フォルダの中でファイルが存在しなくても(空フォルダ)でも削除できます。

Answer (score 1):

※`rm`について補足

`rm` : 対象のファイルを削除する。
`-r` : 再帰的にディレクトリ内部を探査し子孫要素を削除する。
　　　　また、このオプションを付与することでディレクトリを削除できる。
`-f` : 削除に発生する警告を非表示にする。

下記の命令は同じものです。
`rm -r -f`　=　`rm -rf`

例：対象がファイルのみの場合(警告あり)

```
rm *.txt
```

例：対象がディレクトリの場合(警告あり・子孫要素も削除対象)

```
rm -r example_dir
```

例：削除時に警告を発さずディレクトリを子孫要素ごと全て削除する場合

```
rm -rf example_dir
```